# C# Class Library dependencies conflicts

Tags: .net, api, ilmerge

I'm developing API class library and i need to use some external libraries, e.g. log4net, unity, etc. When i reference these libs my API's clients experience problems referencing the same libraries with of another versions. How can make this references 'private' without ILMERGE usage

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing like 'private references'.
The .NET runtime will load any assembly only once into an app's domain and distinguishes them by name only, not by version. Therefore, you'll need to make sure that all of your merged code is actually using the same version of a certain library or allow different versions using [Assembly Version Redirects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (via `<bindingRedirect>` elements in your `app.config`) where appropriate.

Comment: I have log4net merged in dll and referenced sibling with this dll of the same versions. And vs can not understand what is the type of ILog (from which assembly). Is it possible to redirect this?

Comment: You shouldn't do that in the first place: merging a 3rd party library into an assembly and referencing another version of the library from another assembly. This is highly redundant and bad design. But if you absolutely must, you can try to fully qualify the `ILog` occurrences or define an appropriate `namespace` alias.

Comment: the problem i'm using 2 external dlls which conflict each other because of merge hacks, etc. this is specflow project, which references this dlls. i cant change anything %)

Comment: In this case your best bet will be playing around with namespace aliases (and to silently curse the original devs...).